# On the center-stable manifold theorem for sets

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, smooth-manifolds

Suppose I have a dynamical system $f:S \to S$ where $S \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and $S$ is compact and $f$ is twice differentiable. Assume there exists a function $V$ such that $V(f(x)) < V(x)$ unless $x$ is a fixed point of $f$. This implies convergence of $\lim_{k \to \infty}f(x_k)$ with $x_k = f(x_{k-1})$ and moreover you can argue about convergence to the set of fixed points for any initial condition (not point-wise convergence, the set of limit points for a specific initial condition is connected and closed). My question is can I argue that the set of initial conditions so that the the dynamical system converges to a set of fixed points with the Jacobian of these fixed points having an eigenvalue of magnitude greater than one is of measure zero? Essentially, can I argue that the whole component lies on the center-stable manifold? The answer is yes when we have point-wise convergence, i.e., $\lim x_k$ exists.